# Wiring a 4-way switch

Tags: multiway-switch

I just finished resolving an issue I had with a 4-way switch setup but I have a question. I know which end the power starts at but when I get to the 4-way switch, I don't know which bundle is incoming and which one is outgoing. I would have thought it would make a difference since one half of the 4-way switch says In and one half says Out, but I've tried the incoming and outgoing wires in both sets of screws and the switch works fine either way, which was a little surprising. Is this to be expected or does it really matter how the In and Out wires are connected to the 4-way switch. If it matters, I guess I'll need to figure that out somehow, but right now, everything is working.
Thanks, Ed

Answer (score 3):

### In and Out doesn't matter on a 4-way

A four-way (reversing) switch doesn't care about which way it "points" in the circuit -- the functionality works the same nonetheless.  It's no different in spirit than swapping the terminals on a single pole switch, even.

Comment: That's great to hear. Thanks much for your reply!

Comment: Yup. The incoming and outgoing markers are there to indicate pairing of your carriers only.